# How can I make window movement more precise while dragging?

Tags: gnome, mouse, window, compositing

I'd like to know if I can make the dragging of windows/items on the screen more precise. As of, the dragging of windows is very vague. For instance, it's as if the window has some sort of virtual friction, and causes the window to be a bit sloppy, the mouse cursor often overtakes the window and window follows behind. It's not lagging or being choppy at all, it's just sloppy movement. Window movement on OS X 10.8 on the same computer is smooth and precise, the window stays with the cursor exactly. And the same happens on Windows too.

Now, if it's possible, could I improve this sloppiness or just make it more precise than it is now.

I am using Ubuntu GNOME, with Gnome 3.10, this happens on all versions of GNOME I’ve tried too.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I have researched, but I have not found any answers. And I have no idea where to start myself... thanks again.

Comment: Bump! (some chars to fit limit).

Comment: May I ask what kind of system you are using (some kind of a Mac from the sounds of it?)? It would be particularly interesting to know what graphics card you are using and whether or nor you are running the proprietary drivers (e.g. FGLRX for AMD cards). These are factors the desktop rendering performance will depend on.

Comment: @Glutanimate, sorry it's been a long time. I had forgotten about this question. I am using OS X 10.8. It's not actually a Mac. I can't afford a decent Mac. But the card is a GTS 450. Kind of an old card now. But it's good for what I use the computer for, some games, but mostly web development. And this used to happen with the open source and proprietary drivers. My feeling is that it's something to do with X? Because I realised that this also happens on standard and Ubuntu/Unity, OpenSUSE/KDE and Fedora/Gnome 3.10. I haven't used Linux for a while now. Still, I'd like to fix it.